# VS2017 multi project template with shared projects

Tags: visual-studio-2017, project-template, shared-project

I created a multi project template for use with VS2017, including a console application and two shared projects. I can see the template showing up, but whenever I try using it to create a new project I get an error stating that the "projitems"-file of the first shared project was not found in the path \AppData\Local\Temp\<seemingly randomly generated name>\<SharedProjectName>\<SharedProjectName>.projitems. After I dismiss the error the solution is still created, but only the shared projects are in there.

The situation is reproducable by using this template I uploaded to my OneDrive:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!At78FKXjEGEoh7F-vo5XppZBOImatA

And I created the template using this simple solution:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!At78FKXjEGEoh7F_QkSugfzie8I0mg

What I did is:

1. Exported each of the projects individually using "Project" -> "Export Template...".
2. Extracted the exported ZIP files to represent the desired folder structure. Each project got its own folder as you can see in the project template ZIP file.
3. Created a "vstemplate"-file with the help of MSDN, and included the three project files with their relevant paths.
4. Zipped the three folders and the new "vstemplate"-file up and moved it to the Visual Studio templates folder (Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#).

What did I do wrong?